# Why is only one touch being injected when using Touch Injection API with WIN8?

Tags: visual-c++, windows-8, touch

I am trying to test out the Touch Injection API for injecting multiple touches while using Windows 8.
To do this I am creating 5 contacts and then simulating hover and then drag and release.

This works fine for one touch contact.
However nothing changes when I add 4 more contacts i.e. it produces the same as if there was only one contact. (I test by opening Paint on the right side of the screen and visual studio on the left. Then when the program runs a line gets drawn diagonally in the paint window).
When I run GetLastError() after InitializeTouchInjection it gives me 5 which is an invalid access error.

Is there a flag I should be using? Does my computer need to have a certain driver installed? Whats wrong here?

Here is the code:

```
#include <windows.h>

void Drag(int x, int y){
    POINTER_TOUCH_INFO contact_[5];
    BOOL bRet = TRUE;

    InitializeTouchInjection(5, TOUCH_FEEDBACK_DEFAULT);

    for (int c=0;c<5;c++)
    {
        POINTER_TOUCH_INFO &contact=contact_[c];
        memset(&contact, 0, sizeof(POINTER_TOUCH_INFO));
        contact.pointerInfo.pointerType = PT_TOUCH;
        contact.pointerInfo.pointerId = c;          //contact 0
        contact.pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.y = y; // Y co-ordinate of touch on screen
        contact.pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.x = x+50*c; // X co-ordinate of touch on screen

        contact.touchFlags = TOUCH_FLAG_NONE;
        contact.touchMask = TOUCH_MASK_CONTACTAREA | TOUCH_MASK_ORIENTATION | TOUCH_MASK_PRESSURE;
        contact.orientation = 90; // Orientation of 90 means touching perpendicular to screen.
        contact.pressure = 32000; 

        // defining contact area (I have taken area of 4 x 4 pixel)
        contact.rcContact.top = contact.pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.y - 2;
        contact.rcContact.bottom = contact.pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.y + 2;
        contact.rcContact.left = contact.pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.x  - 2;
        contact.rcContact.right = contact.pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.x  + 2;

        //contact.pointerInfo.pointerFlags = POINTER_FLAG_DOWN | POINTER_FLAG_INRANGE | POINTER_FLAG_INCONTACT;
        contact.pointerInfo.pointerFlags = POINTER_FLAG_UPDATE | POINTER_FLAG_INRANGE ;//| POINTER_FLAG_INCONTACT;
    }
    InjectTouchInput(5, contact_); // Injecting the touch down on screen
    Sleep(20);

    for(int i=0;i<200;i++)
    {
        for (int c=0;c<5;c++)
        {
            POINTER_TOUCH_INFO &contact=contact_[c];
            contact.pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.x--; // updating the X Co-ordinate to x-100 pixels
            contact.pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.y++;

            contact.rcContact.top = contact.pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.y - 2;
            contact.rcContact.bottom = contact.pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.y + 2;
            contact.rcContact.left = contact.pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.x  - 2;
            contact.rcContact.right = contact.pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.x  + 2;
            if (i==100)
                contact.pointerInfo.pointerFlags = POINTER_FLAG_INCONTACT | POINTER_FLAG_INRANGE | POINTER_FLAG_DOWN;
            if (i>100)
                contact.pointerInfo.pointerFlags = POINTER_FLAG_INCONTACT | POINTER_FLAG_INRANGE | POINTER_FLAG_UPDATE;
        }
        InjectTouchInput(5, contact_); // Injecting the touch down on screen
        Sleep(20);
    }
    // Lifts the touch input UP
    for (int c=0;c<5;c++)
    {
        POINTER_TOUCH_INFO &contact=contact_[c];
        contact.pointerInfo.pointerFlags = POINTER_FLAG_INRANGE | POINTER_FLAG_UP;
    }
    InjectTouchInput(5, contact_); // Injecting the touch down on screen
    Sleep(10);
}

int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
     Drag(1300,500);
}
```

Comment: A couple of questions: Did `InitializeTouchInjection` return `TRUE`? Note that `TOUCH_FEEDBACK_DEFAULT` is affected by the settings in the **Pen and Touch** control panel - have you tried `TOUCH_FEEDBACK_INDIRECT`?

Comment: @RogerRowland : InitializeTouchInjection comes back as TRUE and immediately afterwards the error is 5. Same thing for TOUCH_FEEDBACK_INDIRECT. I prefer the TOUCH_FEEDBACK_INDIRECT flag because the touch point is clearer but I still cant see more than one touch point. That is the issue. Does the above code work on your computer?

Comment: I can try it - is that everything needed? I'd assumed this was just a section of relevant code.

Comment: That is all that is needed. I can now see five touch points (I didnt change anything except the INDIRECT flag) but I cant get them to all draw a straight line in paint. I open paint on the right side of my window and visual studio on the left. And then I run the above code. In principle it should draw 5 parallel lines next to eachother. Instead it draws one dotted line on the far left.

Comment: Oh, and I used these flags in the first loop: POINTER_FLAG_DOWN | POINTER_FLAG_INRANGE | POINTER_FLAG_INCONTACT

Comment: It works fine for me, I don't get a line in paint but I do get the 5 touch points moving across the screen. Perhaps paint is not multi-touch aware?

Comment: I also get 5 touch points with the INDIRECT flag but I dont get multi draw. Ive seen other programs succesfully send multiple touch points to paint ...

Comment: Well the touch points imply that it's working ok, although I get the five touch points across the middle of my monitors rather than firmly in the paint window.

Comment: In the main function where it says Drag(1300,500); you can change the starting coordinates. If you change them to hit your paint window what happens?

Comment: I get five touch points but just a single line drawn. I don't have a mult-touch screen here so I can't test what paint does with 5 real touches though. Can you?

Comment: Im pretty sure its possible. Ive seen it in a couple of youtube videos.

Comment: @RogerRowland : The solution was simple. If you open Paint and select the brushes tool instead of the pencil tool then you can see all the lines being drawn. You helped guide me so please formally respond to the post and I will award you the bounty. There are 11 hours left before it expires.

Comment: Only 4 hours now, I'll probably miss it, but worth a try :-) We're obviously in different time zones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of points:

Make sure that `InitializeTouchInjection` returned `TRUE`.

Note that `TOUCH_FEEDBACK_DEFAULT` is affected by the settings in the **Pen and Touch** control panel, so use `TOUCH_FEEDBACK_INDIRECT` instead because this overrides those options.