# How to use InjectTouchInput in python for multiple touch

Tags: python, touch, converters

I'm trying to use InjectTouchInput to simulate several touches on the screen.

Everything's fine when I have just one touch but for more-than-one case I'm stuck to a convertion of types problem

Here is the test code:

```
class POINTER_INFO(Structure):
_fields_=[("pointerType",c_uint32),
          ("pointerId",c_uint32),
          ("frameId",c_uint32),
          ("pointerFlags",c_int),
          ("sourceDevice",HANDLE),
          ("hwndTarget",HWND),
          ("ptPixelLocation",POINT),
          ("ptHimetricLocation",POINT),
          ("ptPixelLocationRaw",POINT),
          ("ptHimetricLocationRaw",POINT),
          ("dwTime",DWORD),
          ("historyCount",c_uint32),
          ("inputData",c_int32),
          ("dwKeyStates",DWORD),
          ("PerformanceCount",c_uint64),
          ("ButtonChangeType",c_int)
          ]

class POINTER_TOUCH_INFO(Structure):
_fields_=[("pointerInfo",POINTER_INFO),
          ("touchFlags",c_int),
          ("touchMask",c_int),
          ("rcContact", RECT),
          ("rcContactRaw",RECT),
          ("orientation", c_uint32),
          ("pressure", c_uint32)]


ntouch=2

if (windll.user32.InitializeTouchInjection(ntouch,TOUCH_FEEDBACK_INDIRECT) ==  False): 
    print ("Initialized Touch Injection Error")

tinfo = [POINTER_TOUCH_INFO() for i in range(ntouch)]

tinfo[0].pointerInfo.pointerType = PT_TOUCH
tinfo[0].pointerInfo.pointerId = 0
tinfo[0].pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.y = 1000
tinfo[0].pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.x = 500

tinfo[0].touchFlags = TOUCH_FLAG_NONE
tinfo[0].touchMask = TOUCH_MASK_ALL
tinfo[0].orientation = 90;
tinfo[0].pressure = 32000;
tinfo[0].rcContact.top = tinfo[0].pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.y - 2;
tinfo[0].rcContact.bottom = tinfo[0].pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.y + 2;
tinfo[0].rcContact.left = tinfo[0].pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.x  - 2;
tinfo[0].rcContact.right = tinfo[0].pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.x  + 2;

tinfo[0].pointerInfo.pointerFlags=POINTER_FLAG_DOWN | POINTER_FLAG_INRANGE | POINTER_FLAG_INCONTACT)

tinfo[1].pointerInfo.pointerType = PT_TOUCH
tinfo[1].pointerInfo.pointerId = 1
tinfo[1].pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.y = 900
tinfo[1].pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.x = 300

tinfo[1].touchFlags = TOUCH_FLAG_NONE
tinfo[1].touchMask = TOUCH_MASK_ALL
tinfo[1].orientation = 90;
tinfo[1].pressure = 32000;
tinfo[1].rcContact.top = tinfo[1].pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.y - 2;
tinfo[1].rcContact.bottom = tinfo[1].pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.y + 2;
tinfo[1].rcContact.left = tinfo[1].pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.x  - 2;
tinfo[1].rcContact.right = tinfo[1].pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.x  + 2;

tinfo[1].pointerInfo.pointerFlags=(POINTER_FLAG_DOWN | POINTER_FLAG_INRANGE | POINTER_FLAG_INCONTACT)

if (windll.user32.InjectTouchInput(ntouch, ctypes.byref(tinfo))==0):    
    print (" Error: "+ ctypes.FormatError())
```

The InjectTouchInput function returns the following error:

*TypeError: byref() argument must be a ctypes instance, not 'list'*

I've already tried some casting as passing the result of:

tinfop=(ctypes.Structure*ntouch)(*tinfo)

but in this case it returns:

*TypeError: _type_ must have storage info*

If ntouch=1 (single touch) the code works fine.

The examples I've been able to find are only c++ (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875283/why-is-only-one-touch-being-injected-when-using-touch-injection-api-with-win8  or single touch python.

Basically I think I'm looking a way to convert a list of Structure into a pointer to their first item.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue by changing the definition of tinfo as:

```
tinfo = (POINTER_TOUCH_INFO * ntouch)()
```

This link was helpfull: [Passing an array of struct from Python to dll](https://chrisheydrick.com/2016/02/06/passing-a-ctypes-array-of-struct-from-python-to-dll/)