# AutoHotkey - How to inject multi-touch (single touch works)

Tags: touch, autohotkey, multi-touch

So, I've been playing around and managed to recreate 'touch and hold' and 'touch and drag' events. However for some reason I wasn't able to create a second touch. I know the code is messy, I was just trying to understand what each parts mean.

What I've been trying is to change this part from 0 to 1 when creating a second touch ID, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
NumPut(0, contact1, 4, "UInt") ; .pointerInfo.pointerId     //contact 0
.
.
.
NumPut(1, contact2, 4, "UInt") ; .pointerInfo.pointerId     //contact 1
```

Here is the whole code for reference, I feel I'm missing something trivial.

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v1.1.33+

is32bit := A_PtrSize = 4 

; ****************
;     TOUCH 1
; ****************

F2::

; 2] Initialize the Touch Injection API refer code below.
VarSetCapacity(contact1, is32bit ? 136 : 144, 0)
TOUCH_FEEDBACK_DEFAULT := 0x1
DllCall("InitializeTouchInjection", "UInt", 1, "UInt", TOUCH_FEEDBACK_DEFAULT) ; Here number of contact point is declared as 1.

; 3] Define the contact Point, this definition contains contact type, contact location ,contact area, pressure and orientation .
PT_TOUCH := 2
NumPut(PT_TOUCH, contact1, 0, "UInt") ; .pointerInfo.pointerType
NumPut(0, contact1, 4, "UInt") ; .pointerInfo.pointerId     //contact 0
NumPut(x := 1200, contact1, is32bit ? 24 : 32, "Int") ; .pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.x  // X co-ordinate of touch on screen
NumPut(y := 200, contact1, is32bit ? 28 : 36, "Int") ; .pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.y   // Y co-ordinate of touch on screen

; #define TOUCH_FLAG_NONE                 0x00000000 // Default
TOUCH_FLAG_NONE := 0x00000000
NumPut(TOUCH_FLAG_NONE, contact1, is32bit ? 88 : 96, "UInt") ; .touchFlags

TOUCH_MASK_CONTACTAREA := 0x00000001
TOUCH_MASK_ORIENTATION := 0x00000002
TOUCH_MASK_PRESSURE := 0x00000004
NumPut(TOUCH_MASK_CONTACTAREA | TOUCH_MASK_ORIENTATION | TOUCH_MASK_PRESSURE, contact1, is32bit ? 92 : 100, "UInt") ; .touchMask

NumPut(90, contact1, is32bit ? 128 : 136, "UInt") ; .orientation    // Orientation of 90 means touching perpendicular to screen.
NumPut(32000, contact1, is32bit ? 132 : 140, "UInt") ; .pressure

; defining contact area (I have taken area of 4 x 4 pixel)
NumPut(y - 2, contact1, is32bit ? 100 : 108, "Int") ; .rcContact.top
NumPut(y + 2, contact1, is32bit ? 108 : 116, "Int") ; .rcContact.bottom
NumPut(x - 2, contact1, is32bit ? 96 : 104, "Int") ; .rcContact.left
NumPut(x + 2, contact1, is32bit ? 104 : 112, "Int") ; .rcContact.right


; 4] Implementing use case 1 , Injecting Touching down on screen.

POINTER_FLAG_DOWN := 0x00010000
POINTER_FLAG_INRANGE := 0x00000002
POINTER_FLAG_INCONTACT := 0x00000004
NumPut(POINTER_FLAG_DOWN | POINTER_FLAG_INRANGE | POINTER_FLAG_INCONTACT, contact1, 12, "UInt") ; .pointerInfo.pointerFlags
DllCall("InjectTouchInput", "UInt", 1, "Ptr", &contact1) ; Injecting the touch down on screen

; Touch and Hold

POINTER_FLAG_UPDATE := 0x00020000
POINTER_FLAG_INRANGE := 0x00000002
POINTER_FLAG_INCONTACT := 0x00000004
NumPut(POINTER_FLAG_UPDATE | POINTER_FLAG_INRANGE | POINTER_FLAG_INCONTACT, contact1, 12, "UInt") ; .pointerInfo.pointerFlags

Loop, 100
{
    DllCall("InjectTouchInput", "UInt", 1, "Ptr", &contact1) ; Injecting the touch down on screen
    Sleep, 10
}
return

F3::
; 5] Implementing use case 2 , Injecting Touching Up from screen.
POINTER_FLAG_UP := 0x00040000
NumPut(POINTER_FLAG_UP, contact1, 12, "UInt") ; .pointerInfo.pointerFlags
DllCall("InjectTouchInput", "UInt", 1, "Ptr", &contact1) ; Injecting the touch Up from screen
return

; ****************
;     TOUCH 2
; ****************
F7::
; 2] Initialize the Touch Injection API refer code below.
VarSetCapacity(contact2, is32bit ? 136 : 144, 0)
TOUCH_FEEDBACK_DEFAULT := 0x1
DllCall("InitializeTouchInjection", "UInt", 1, "UInt", TOUCH_FEEDBACK_DEFAULT) ; Here number of contact point is declared as 1.


; 3] Define the contact Point, this definition contains contact type, contact location ,contact area, pressure and orientation .

PT_TOUCH := 2
NumPut(PT_TOUCH, contact2, 0, "UInt") ; .pointerInfo.pointerType
NumPut(1, contact2, 4, "UInt") ; .pointerInfo.pointerId     //contact 1
NumPut(x := 1200, contact2, is32bit ? 24 : 32, "Int") ; .pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.x  // X co-ordinate of touch on screen
NumPut(y := 400, contact2, is32bit ? 28 : 36, "Int") ; .pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.y   // Y co-ordinate of touch on screen

; #define TOUCH_FLAG_NONE                 0x00000000 // Default
TOUCH_FLAG_NONE := 0x00000000
NumPut(TOUCH_FLAG_NONE, contact2, is32bit ? 88 : 96, "UInt") ; .touchFlags

TOUCH_MASK_CONTACTAREA := 0x00000001
TOUCH_MASK_ORIENTATION := 0x00000002
TOUCH_MASK_PRESSURE := 0x00000004
NumPut(TOUCH_MASK_CONTACTAREA | TOUCH_MASK_ORIENTATION | TOUCH_MASK_PRESSURE, contact2, is32bit ? 92 : 100, "UInt") ; .touchMask

NumPut(90, contact2, is32bit ? 128 : 136, "UInt") ; .orientation    // Orientation of 90 means touching perpendicular to screen.
NumPut(32000, contact2, is32bit ? 132 : 140, "UInt") ; .pressure

; defining contact area (I have taken area of 4 x 4 pixel)
NumPut(y - 2, contact2, is32bit ? 100 : 108, "Int") ; .rcContact.top
NumPut(y + 2, contact2, is32bit ? 108 : 116, "Int") ; .rcContact.bottom
NumPut(x - 2, contact2, is32bit ? 96 : 104, "Int") ; .rcContact.left
NumPut(x + 2, contact2, is32bit ? 104 : 112, "Int") ; .rcContact.right


; 4] Implementing use case 1 , Injecting Touching down on screen.

POINTER_FLAG_DOWN := 0x00010000
POINTER_FLAG_INRANGE := 0x00000002
POINTER_FLAG_INCONTACT := 0x00000004
NumPut(POINTER_FLAG_DOWN | POINTER_FLAG_INRANGE | POINTER_FLAG_INCONTACT, contact2, 12, "UInt") ; .pointerInfo.pointerFlags
DllCall("InjectTouchInput", "UInt", 1, "Ptr", &contact2) ; Injecting the touch down on screen

; Touch and Hold

POINTER_FLAG_UPDATE := 0x00020000
POINTER_FLAG_INRANGE := 0x00000002
POINTER_FLAG_INCONTACT := 0x00000004
NumPut(POINTER_FLAG_UPDATE | POINTER_FLAG_INRANGE | POINTER_FLAG_INCONTACT, contact2, 12, "UInt") ; .pointerInfo.pointerFlags

Loop, 100
{
    DllCall("InjectTouchInput", "UInt", 1, "Ptr", &contact2) ; Injecting the touch down on screen
    Sleep, 10
}
return

F8::
; 5] Implementing use case 2 , Injecting Touching Up from screen.
POINTER_FLAG_UP := 0x00040000
NumPut(POINTER_FLAG_UP, contact2, 12, "UInt") ; .pointerInfo.pointerFlags
DllCall("InjectTouchInput", "UInt", 1, "Ptr", &contact2) ; Injecting the touch Up from screen
return

#Esc::
ExitApp
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875283/why-is-only-one-touch-being-injected-when-using-touch-injection-api-with-win8) could be of help?

Comment: Thanks. I tried to change the flag to TOUCH_FEEDBACK_INDIRECT but the problem is still the same. I trigger the first touch, then in the middle I trigger the second one and the first stops in the position, keep touching the screen while the second touch is not registered as a touch on the screen, but it looks it is touching it.